# pandas Dataframe redesign/reorder issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this one :

[raw Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZea.png)

and want to get a Dataframe like this manual crafted one.

[wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MJYS.png)

i have tried to do it with the follwing commands

```
SD = station_data.set_index('ELEMENT')
SD.reset_index(inplace=True)
SD = SD.groupby(['ELEMENT'])
result = SD['VALUE'].unique()
result.reset_index(inplace=False)
SD = pd.DataFrame(result)
SD = SD.transpose()
```

the problem with this is , that .unique() is wrong cause you can get the same value multiple times and the values aren't a single object anymore.so i'm searching a way to get the wanted Dataframe with all values.

the output of the commandblock is:

```
                        VALUE
ELEMENT 
HUMIDITY                [98.0, 97.0, 96.0, 95.0, 94.0, 92.0, 93.0, 91....
PRECIPITATION_FORM      [<NA>]
PRECIPITATION_HEIGHT    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5,...
...
```

let us use the following gutted Dataframe as example.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'STATION_ID': [1207, 1207, 1207,1207, 1207, 1207,1207, 1207, 1207],
                'DATE': ['2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0','2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0','2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0'],
                'ELEMENT': ['TEMPERATURE_AIR_200','TEMPERATURE_AIR_200','TEMPERATURE_AIR_200', 'HUMIDITY','HUMIDITY','HUMIDITY', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200'],
                'VALUE': [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 98.0, 96.0, 98.0, -0.3,0.1,0.4]})
```

Comment: i hope after the changes i  made it's better then before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have data in "long" format, and you want your data in "wide" format. This can be done in Pandas using either [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) or [unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

Here's an example of how to do it with unstack().

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'STATION_ID': [1207, 1207, 1207,1207, 1207, 1207,1207, 1207, 1207],
                'DATE': ['2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0','2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0','2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:0'],
                'ELEMENT': ['TEMPERATURE_AIR_200','TEMPERATURE_AIR_200','TEMPERATURE_AIR_200', 'HUMIDITY','HUMIDITY','HUMIDITY', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200', 'TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200'],
                'VALUE': [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 98.0, 96.0, 98.0, -0.3,0.1,0.4]})

# Set indexes so pandas knows which columns to unstack by
test = test.set_index(['STATION_ID', 'DATE', 'ELEMENT'])
test = test.unstack()

# The column names are now a multiindex. Fix that
test.columns = test.columns.get_level_values(1)

# Put the index back how it was. Optional.
test = test.reset_index()
print(test)
```

Output:

```
ELEMENT  STATION_ID                 DATE  HUMIDITY  TEMPERATURE_AIR_200  TEMPERATURE_DEW_POINT_200
0              1207  2019-01-01 00:00:00      98.0                  0.1                       -0.3
1              1207  2019-01-01 01:00:00      96.0                  0.1                        0.1
2              1207   2019-01-01 02:00:0      98.0                  0.4                        0.4
```

Comment: thanks for your description of the problem and the precise solution